# Dual Boot System Operating System not Found (Win7/Ubunty 14.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, grubrescue

I read through similar problems, but nothing I found solved my particular problem.

I used to run a dual boot WIn7/Ubuntu 14.04. I was in Windows when suddenly the screen froze. Cursor was still active but couldn't do anything within the OS (not even start task manager). So I tried a hard restart. Once it restarted I was met by the message:

> operating system not found

Grub Rescue loads.

```
ls

(hd0) (hd0,msdos1)
```

Then when I try

```
ls (hd0)
ls (hd0-,msdos1)
```

it returns:

> File system unknown.

Any suggestions how to back into the OS without wiping the hard disk? There is some data, I really cannot lose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. I was not able to get help no matter how much I perused the internet. The only way that I was able to save my data and restore the OS's was to pull the internal hard drive, put it in another computer, and manually pull the important files that I needed. If it is a program that you are trying to save, I have no experience in this. I was trying to save college term papers, projects, and such.

Comment: Exactly what I need to do lol. So basically take the hard drives out and add them as a secondary to another system? At this point I wish I still had a desktop.